# Global import vs individual component import + webpack: is there any difference in final (bundled/packed) size?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I found similar topic [What are the pros/cons of importing components in main.js (for VueJS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766911/what-are-the-pros-cons-of-importing-components-in-main-js-for-vuejs) but I want to dig a bit deeper.

For example, [bootsrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) allows to import all components together via `main.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
```

or any component individually, like:

```
import bAlert from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components/alert/alert';
Vue.component('b-alert', bAlert);
```

Many components of `bootstrap-vue` I simply do not use, so, here I have 2 questions:

1. Does `webpack` add to bundled/packed version of site just really used components (Somehow checks which components are used? Is it necessary to specify any `Webpack` settings?) or `webpack` simply adds everything what is globally imported (in `main.js`)?
2. Based on the 1st question: Is there any profitability in size of bundled/packed (if to use `webpack`) site in case of using just individual components?

I have quite a big project with lots of components imported in `main.js` and I would like to know, should I leave it as is or re-organize everything.

**UPDATE**

I replaced `Vue.use(BoostrapVue)` by components which I need (I use quite a lot). With `Vue.use(BoostrapVue)` after `npm run build` my `dist` folder was 4.6MB. Once I started to import each needed component the `dist` folder size became 4.2MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you import * webpack won't be able to know what things were not used, and what thigs were. It will put everything in the final bundle.

Best practices is to use named imports, so they can be "treeshaked".

Comment: So, based on the example with `bootstrap-vue`,  is it preferable to import `component individually` rather than `all components together via main.js`, as shown above, correct? In this case the final bundle's size will me smaller and as a result site can be downloaded faster, right?

Comment: Yes. Just get what you need, preferably from the es distribution (`'bootstrap-vue/es/components'`)